# Headphone jack dusty or broken?

Tags: headphone-jack, lg-optimus

Recently I have been having trouble with my LG Optimus F60. At first, whenever I'm listening to music through Google play music, the music suddenly stops halfway and when I click the play button, it goes to play the previous song. I assumed it was a bug in the app so I never gave it much though, but now, the music stops entirely while I'm using my headphones.  The song will either pause as if I removed the headphones or the song will start to play through the phone's speaker WHILE the headphones are plugged in. I've tried blowing into the hole and even tried canned air in case it was dust or lint. I've only had the phone for just barely 4 months. Can anyone help me figure out what the problem is? Can't afford to get a another new phone right now.

Comment: Did you try another music player? What are your results?

Comment: It was the same issue with the other player

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. First check whether you have the same issue with another set of headphones. If it persists, change your headphones. Even if there is no issue with the headphone, it might not be compatible with your device. So always check with a compatible model.
2. Check the headphones with your default music player to make sure there is no bug in Google play music. Even, in his case, switching headphones is recommended.
3. If none of the above work, you can easily fix this from an authorized support center, this is a minor fix that would be done free under warranty, and certainly won't set you back more than $10 without a warranty.

However it is very unlikely that this has anything to do with the phone, most probably swapping headphones will work.

Comment: @Antoinella, while doing the above try to see whether an headphone without mic or control buttons work normally. I suspect the button in the headphone with which one can pause or skip track is posing you trouble - in case your troublesome headphone has one.

Comment: @Narayanan the headphones I use don't have a mic or any button on them.